# Unable to view tables created in hive through Spark in Unix Shell Terminal

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, bigdata

Are the tables created in hive through shell and through Spark (Scala on Eclipse) are all the same?

If yes I'm getting different lists of tables and databases when working with them.
How to fix that?

Comment: All are same.  Can you explain the context in which you see different list of tables?

Comment: While I'm using HiveContext and creating a table in Spark, those tables are not being shown in user/hive/warehouse. Can you tell me the possible correction for that.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide as much information as possible. For e.g. include the spark code that creates table and how you are checking /user/hive/warehouse dir? Is it through Hue or HDFS and so on.

Comment: Please post the code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Spark needs the configuration to detect Hive.

Add `hive-site.xml` in your classpath.

Without these configurations, Spark will store the hive tables locally in a `metastore_db` folder in your project root.